# How can $b$ be non-zero in the hyperplane formula $a^T x = b$?

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

I am trying to understand how $b$ can be any other number than $0$. Since $a$ must be orthogonal to $x$, then their dot product, $a^Tx$, must be equal to $0$. So if $b$ is any other number than $0$, then wouldn't the dot product not be $0$ and therefore not orthogonal?

I am told that $b$ is the shift from the origin but I do not understand why that is.

Comment: Not all hyperplanes pass through the origin.

Comment: I don't understand how that explains my dilemma of $a$ being orthogonal to $x$ even when their dot product is not equal to 0.

Comment: $${\bf a}^\top \left( {\bf x} - {\bf x}_0 \right) = 0$$

Comment: Do you agree that the equation x+y=42 determines a line in the plane?

Comment: A good strategy when you come across what seems is a contradiction is to write down in detail your reasoning and then go through it checking with care every single claim you main, even those that are obvious. In this case, you'd have problems when you get to "since a must be orthogonal to x". That phrase is not wrong, really: it does not even make sense, for x is a variable.

Comment: I apologize for my poor math/linear algebra skills as there may be something obvious that I am not seeing. 

I do not understand why my statement does not make sense given that x is a variable. I know that whatever vector $x$ is, it must be orthogonal to $a$. And since it must be orthogonal to $a$, any dot product between any $x$ and $a$ must be equal to $0$. So why does it matter whether $x$ is a variable or not? 

I think I am missing the point but do not understand why this logic does not make sense.

Comment: @boogiewoogie As an example, think about the equation for a line: y = mx + b. Rearrange this to get y - mx = b, which is the same as $[-m, 1]^T [x, y] = b$.

Comment: I want to thank everyone and their efforts to help me understand this problem. I see after working out $a^T(x-x_{0}) = 0$ that $x_{0}$ is equal to a point on the plane and you will end up with a constant on the left hand side of the equation and that gets simply moved over to the right hand side. I think this is what you were getting at? However now I need to seek to understand what $a^Tx_{0}$ means to the equation when it is moved to the right hand side.

Comment: How you can think about this: $a^Tx$ is the projection of $x$ onto $a$ (or at least proportional to it). The equation $a^Tx=b$ describes all points which have the same magnitude after being projected onto $a$. This is a plane that is perpendicular to $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be any hyperplane. The argument I'll use works just fine for arbitrary $n\in \mathbb{N}$, but because it might be easier to visualise, consider $n =3$, hence $U$ is a plane. Such plane $U$ can be expressed by its normal vector, let's call it $a\in \mathbb{R}^3$ just as you considered, and it will be expressed as the set of points that are orthogonal to $a$. However, that is not all there is to it.

If your plane contains the zero vector, $U$ will be a vectorspace and your description works fine, but, if $0\not \in U$, you need to specify which of all the planes whose normal vector is $a\in \mathbb{R}^3$ is $U$.

For that matter, assume $p = (p_1,p_2,p_3) \in U$ is a known point of $U$. If $y\in U$, the vector difference $y-p$ belongs to the plane $U_0 = \lbrace \langle a, x\rangle = 0, x\in \mathbb{R}^3\rbrace$, that is, the parallel vector to $U$ that contains the zero vector, i.e., you've got that the points of $y\in U$ satisfy $\langle a, y-p\rangle = 0$ and such thing is $$0 = \langle a, y-p\rangle = (a_1,a_2,a_3)\cdot (y_1-p_1, y_2-p_2, y_3-p_3)^T = \sum_{i=1}^3a_i (y_i-p_i) \\
= \sum_{i=1}^3a_i y_i -\sum_{i=1}^3a_i p_i = \langle a, y\rangle - \langle a,p\rangle$$ where $\langle a,p\rangle\in \mathbb{R}$, so you might just call it $b=\langle a,p\rangle$ and hence your question follows. The answer could've been better written, I guess, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I think that was a great and very detailed way to show what I was missing. Thank you very much for this!